# .Net Maui - Grid in a Horizontal of Both ScrollView not formatting correctly

Tags: grid, scrollview, maui

I would like to add a scrollable (vertically and horizontally) Grid in a row of an outer Grid. I want to set the Grid column widths based on the GridUnitType.Star.
I can achieve this when the SrollView orientation is set to Vertical but not when set to Horizontal or Both.
The following XAML demonstrates this:

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiGrids.MainPage">

    <Grid Margin="20" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
            <Label Text="Column 1 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="Column 2 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Column 3 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The column widths of the outer and vertical grid are correctly set based on the Star value but these values are ignored in the case of the horizontal grid.

[Code output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxhdO.png)

I was able to do this in Xamarin Forms but does not seem possible in Maui. Am I missing something.

Comment: Do you run it on Android or Windows platform? I made a small change based on your code and it works well on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code snippet below that works well on Android for the Maui, you can refer to it:

```
 <Grid Margin="20" >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Label Text="Column 1 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="Column 2 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Column 3 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I use the Windows Platform when developing, tends to be quicker to load.

Comment: I tried this answer but gor the same result in Wndows, Android - Portrait and Android - Landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Think I am a good part the way there.
It appears unlike the vertical ScrollView the horizontal ScrollView needs to have a width or a child with a specific width.
I have named the outerGrid, the horizontalGrid and the verticalGrid in the XAML.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiGrids.MainPage">

    <Grid Margin="20" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="outerGrid" Grid.Row="0" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
            <Label Text="Column 1 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <Label Text="Column 2 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Label Text="Column 3 Outer" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Both" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Default"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
            <Grid x:Name="horizontalGrid" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Default">
            <Grid x:Name="verticalGrid" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*,3*">
                <Label Text="Column 1 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="Column 2 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="Column 3 Vertical" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
```

and then set the grid widths in code behind based on the defaulted outerGrid width as follows:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        outerGrid.Loaded += OuterGrid_Loaded;
        this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
    }

    private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        horizontalGrid.WidthRequest = outerGrid.Width;
        verticalGrid.WidthRequest = outerGrid.Width;
    }

    private void OuterGrid_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        horizontalGrid.WidthRequest = outerGrid.Width;
        verticalGrid.WidthRequest = outerGrid.Width;
    }
```

This works in Windows when the form is displayed and resized. Also works in Android, both portrait and landscape.